# Task-level parallelism from gradle's project-level parallelism?

Tags: parallel-processing, gradle

I've got a gradle build process that **dynamically** generates a list of ~200 homogeneous, CPU-intensive processing tasks (all of the same task type).  *The tasks in this list do not depend on one another, but they have commen ancestors and common descendants in my build.*

It doesn't look like gradle has a built-in way to let me process these in parallel.  (The only parallel abstraction I see has to do with decoupled projects).

Are there any techniques I could apply on top, or am I stuck?

For example, could I dynamically create `n` projects (somehow "decoupled" from the main project to satisfy Gradle's parallel processing requirements), each with `1/n` of the tasks I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks belonging to the same project cannot currently be executed in parallel. You could script `settings.gradle` to create many subprojects and script `build.gradle` to assign tasks to projects, but that might not be a very convenient solution. Another option is to have a single task that internally parallelizes the work (e.g. using the [GPars](https://github.com/GPars/GPars) library).